# InterruptionException throwing time during wait method

Tags: java, multithreading

In the JavaDoc of Object class, in the method wait(long timeout) it is described like below

> "If the current thread is interrupted by any thread before or while it is waiting, then an InterruptedException is thrown"

what is meant by "before" in the above statement? before executing  obj.wait() means before executing any instruction defined above it?

```
synchronized (obj) {
         while (<condition does not hold>)
             obj.wait(timeout);
         ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
     }
```

Comment: May be because wait(timout) checks for the threads if started or not. If not then throws exception

Comment: What is  this 'obj'? Is it thread object?

Comment: obj can be any object..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is meant by "before" in the above statement? before executing
> obj.wait() means before executing any instruction defined above it?

This means if the thread gets/got interrupted before call to the `wait()` method is executed, this would still result in throwing the `InterruptedException` when the actual call to `wait()` happens.

To try this scenario I wrote below code that starts the Threads and interrupts it. The `run()` method of this thread loops for `INTEGER.MAX_VALE-1` times and calls the `wait()` method. By the time it reaches the call to `wait()` method the thread got interrupted. And subsequently during the call to `wait()` it threw `InterruptedException`.

```
public class ThreadWaitInterruption {
    static Object obj = new Object();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Started Thread");
                for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
                    int j = i/2;
                }
                
                System.out.println("Loop completed");
                
                synchronized (obj) {
                    try {
                        obj.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Interrupting");
        t.interrupt();
        System.out.println("Interuupted");
    }
}
```

The sample output, tested with 1.8 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit.

```
Interrupting
Started Thread
Interuupted
Loop completed
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at com.demo.threads.ThreadWaitInterruption$1.run(ThreadWaitInterruption.java:19)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

OR

```
Started Thread
Interrupting
Interuupted
Loop completed
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at com.demo.threads.ThreadWaitInterruption$1.run(ThreadWaitInterruption.java:19)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So calling the `wait()` method on an interrupted thread resulted in `InterruptedException` being thrown even if the thread got interrupted before the call to the `wait()` method.

**NOTE:** As it is multi-thread program, the above order of output is not guaranteed and we may have to run this program couple to get the exact above output.

Comment: I suggest that you define the `Object obj` outside the `run` method (make it a field, maybe). Even though you are illustrating something else, there is no point in synchronizing on a local variable.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade That is a good suggestion and incorporated. Just made it a static field in `ThreadWaitInterruption` class.

Answer (score 1):

The call to Thread#interrupt results *only* in setting the interrupted flag on the thread, for interruption to work it requires the cooperation of the thread being interrupted. The task being interrupted needs to do either of the following:

- check the interrupted flag (using `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`) or
- do something that can throw an InterruptedException (wait/sleep/join/etc.)

in order for the interruption to have any effect.

Methods like wait or sleep throw InterruptedException based on them detecting that the interrupted flag is currently set in the calling thread. The interrupted flag may have been set prior to the method having been entered.

If you have nested threadsafe components that incorporate waits, sleeps, or joins, then when one component receives an interruption it can either let the InterruptedException be thrown or it can catch the exception and restore the interrupt flag (which was cleared when the exception was thrown). This way all the pieces in your component that are being traversed by that thread can be aware of the pending cancellation and can  terminate what they're doing in a responsive manner.